# are needed to vs are needed for

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence which proposition should I use?

*> Metals are needed ... the green technology.*

- a) **for**
- b) **to**

---

How about this sentence?

*> Metals are needed ... power electric cars.*

Comment: _Green technology_ is a noun phrase. _Power_ here is a verb. Does that help?

Comment: This entire question is a red herring. You just need to learn the difference between the prepositions "to" and "for", which you could do from a dictionary.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. Instead of `to vs for` I googled this question's title but I didn't find any useful content so I asked in this forum. I thought it was something about verb `need`'s preposition. @Astralbee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I believe what you're really asking is what the difference is between "are needed for" and "are needed to".

"...are needed for..." is always followed by a *noun phrase* because "for" is a *preposition*.

"... are needed to..." is always followed by an *infinitive verb* because that's the *infinitive "to"*, not a preposition at all.